# C# - Cannot get value from database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, select, authentication

In my application I have a login system. It's basic so I don't need any encryption. The problem is that when I want to login, I insert the credentials (username and password) but it doesn't make anything. My code is:

```
 public void iniciarsessaobutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string txtuser = textusername.Text;
     string txtpass = textlogin.Text;      

     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT password FROM empregados WHERE user='" + txtuser + "';", mConn);
     mConn.Open();           
     MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();            
     login.Read();            
     string getpass = login["password"].ToString();

     if (getpass == txtpass)
     {                
         mConn.Close();
         MessageBox.Show("Sessão iniciada");
         Admin adm = new Admin();
         this.Hide();
         adm.Show();
     }
     else
     {
         mConn.Close();
         MessageBox.Show("Não foi possivel iniciar sessão. Insira a password corretamente.");
     }            
 }
```

Comment: Is the `mConn` variable initialized anywhere?

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code using the debugger? I'm pretty sure it does *something* but obviously not what you expect it to do.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and is generally insecure. Passwords should not be stored in a database as plain text.

Comment: I use mConn correctly, and it works in other parts of the code.

Comment: My password is just a 4 digit number, it doesn't have almost any security.

Comment: When I start the app it works normally and when I click in the login button it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I know the problem is before the if clauses, because it doesn't enter.

Comment: Most likely you're getting an exception because you are trying to `mConn.Open()` when it is already opened elsewhere in your code. Do not try to "recycle" your connection in that way - create a new connection where you need it and dispose it. Preferably wrap your connection and command into `using() {}` blocks to have them auto-closed and auto-disposed.

Comment: I'd tried, and still doesn't work @Filburt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to propose some fixes mentioned in the comments along with some general improvements. See my comments in the code for the issues addressed:

```
public void iniciarsessaobutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txtuser = textusername.Text;
    string txtpass = textlogin.Text;

    // Put your connection into a using() block
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(variableWithYourConnectionStringHere))
    {
        // Put your commend into a using() block
        // enclose your column names in backticks to avoid conflict with MySql reserved keywords
        // add a placeholder (@username) for your parameter
        // use LIMIT 1 if you only expect 1 row matching your condition
        using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT `password` FROM empregados WHERE `user` = @username LIMIT 1", conn))
        {
            mConn.Open();

            // add a parameter with your TextBox value
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtuser);

            // If you only retrieve 1 value, use ExecuteScalar to return only 1 value
            // cast the returned object as string
            string getpass = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;

            if (getpass == txtpass)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sessão iniciada");
                Admin adm = new Admin();
                this.Hide();
                adm.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não foi possivel iniciar sessão. Insira a password corretamente.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said bat it continues not working @Filbort . Here is my code: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0UsguTsdfErS1FsdHl0ckRSOWM)